# Stop word-wrap in html

Tags: html, css

I don't want word wrap but this is being. I have set width more than text length but this is still breaking so how can I stop word break.

css

```
.menu{
    float:left;
    width:120px;
    height:34px;
    padding:12px 6px 0 6px;
    color:#cc8d50;

}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try:

```
.menu{
    white-space: nowrap;
...
```

Add that to your CSS.

Answer (score 6):

In your css insert this:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```